# How to run an ant project via Idea Intellij

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I have downloaded the following project via svn.

[>link to Jate<](https://code.google.com/p/jatetoolkit/wiki/JATEIntro)

Now I want to run the project, preferably via Intellij.

I have been trying for a while but I can't seem to get it to run.

I don't have any prior experience with Ant.

What I want to do in pseudocode is:

```
RUN classname arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: take a look @ : https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/ant-build-tool-window.html . And you can run java class wrapped within target..

Comment: Do I need to edit some xml files to make it work? All I get from clicking "play" is "All files are up-to-date"

Comment: You can bring up ant build window, by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `a` ( which opens up Actions text box ), search for 'Ant Build' which lists targets from your build.xml, select required target & click run button to run it

Comment: I'm not sure if the `Ant Support` plugin needs to be enabled for this?

Comment: Thanks +1, True, @Havnar you can take a look at this : https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/ant.html . Usually it comes as bundled plugin to IntelliJ.

Comment: Ant is enabled, and I can get to that menu, it's just that it builds something in about a second but I don't know where to go from there. (The build is successful) how do I run a (test) class then?